# Failed to load template: uib/template/modal/window.html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I feel like i have attempted everything and i still get the error:

> Failed to load template: uib/template/modal/window.html

in my index file i have added the following:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
```

in my app file ive added:

```
    'ui.bootstrap',
```

And in my controller file ive added the following:

```
$uibModal
```

and

```
this.openPayment = function () {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
        ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
        templateUrl: 'payment.html',
        controller: 'paymentController',
        controllerAs: '$ctrl',
        size: 'lg',
    });
}
```

in my `paymentController` i have added the following:

```
angular.module('Payment').controller('paymentController', function ($uibModalInstance) {
    var ctrl = this;
});
```

And `payment.html`:

```
    <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title" translate="ACADEMY.EDIT.COURSES.CREATE"></h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
</div>
<div class="lb-modal-footer">
    <a class="btn btn-grey" tooltip="{{ 'TOOLTIP.CANCEL' | translate }}" ng-click="CTRL.cancel()"><i
            class="fa fa-ban"></i></a>
    <button class="btn btn-success m-l-xs {{CTRL.academyCourse.course ? '':'disabled'}}" tooltip="{{ 'TOOLTIP.SAVE_AND_EXIT' | translate }}" ng-click="CTRL.addCourse()"><i
            class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i></button>
</div>
```

So can anyone tell me what ive done wrong?

Comment: can u make a plunkr ?

Comment: Is your payment.html in a folder structure? You have to put the path to it. Look in your browser and see where it is trying to load it from, and see if that is where it is. Also look into a template cache, later on to do it right. Yo will have to use Gulp or Angular Template Cache.. Can you show the the structure of your app, your folder structure. I get it just can't find it where you think it is, normally it looks something like app/My folder/my controller/template.html

Comment: @Maccurt The url is correct i have tried different paths and each time i get this error!

Comment: So if you put templateUrl:uib/template/modal/window.html it won't work?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

1. Make sure you have either attached the template version of ui-bootstrap or the one without.

   ```
   <!-- remove this -->
   <!--<script src="node_modules/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>--> 
   <script src="node_modules/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
   ```

In your case, you're missing the modal template (`uib/template/modal/window.html`), so I would keep the `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js`.

2. Make sure you are properly linking to the script, go to the page source and try reaching the uib script, It's possible you have built your project but the script file wasn't added into the build.
3. make sure you are adding the uib script **after** you add the angular script and **after** you add the bootstrap files in your index.html

Comment: Thank you. I just did a massive cleanup on project and replaced all the libraries with the latest versions, and this happened to me. Turns out I had loaded both libraries as well. (face-palm). Removing the reference to ui-bootstrap.js fixed everything.

Answer (score 2):

I solve this program buy  removing the reference to ui-bootstrap.js, using  the reference to ui-bootstrap-tpls.js only, fixed everything.